# Intel C++ Compiler reveals errors unseen by Visual Studio 2013 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, intel

Why is Intel C++ Compiler stumbling on errors that the Visual Studio 2013 compiler does not see ?

errors are three errors of type: `error: declaration is incompatible with` as for instance

```
Error   8   error : declaration is incompatible with "void gauss<nzx,      
iv>::myfun_new(const coef_struct<nf, 
nzx> &, const inversion_controls_struct *, const 
inversion_interOut_struct *, double *)" 
(declared at line 139 of xxxx)
```

where declaration is in header file,

```
template<int nzx, int iv> void gaussNewton<nzx,iv>::myfun_new(const 
coef_struct<nf,nzx>& j, 
const inversion_controls_struct *inv_Controls, const 
inversion_inter_struct *inter, double* __restrict cob)
```

Any idea for this particular case ? Something to do with `__restrict` keyword ? More generally, what makes one compiler more sensitive than another ?

**edit**

with more troubleshooting, I find that only those methods with an argument of type

```
template<int nf, int nzx> struct coef_struct{}
```

are in trouble, that is to say only method with one argumente of type a templatized struct

Comment: What is the context of the `myfun_new` function? Is it a member function? Should it be declared `static`?

Comment: I had to edit. yes, it is a member function of `template<int nzx, int iv> class gaussNew : public gaussNewBase
{};`

Comment: And `gaussNewton` inherits from `gauss`? Either way, how is the function declared in the `gauss` class?

Comment: had to edit, thnaks for the int ; signature is not an issue apparently, only there is this `__restrict`

Comment: had to edit again. found that only occurs on method with one argumente of type a templatized struct

Comment: I think it's time you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I have same problem. No answer here!